# Positioning of controls within DIV

Tags: css

I have a set of controls that will show/hide when the user clicks a button. The controls consist of a grid, 2 labels, a dropdown, a text box and another button. I would like to position them as follows:

[image]

I have the grid positioned correctly but the dropdown and textbox controls are to the left but below the grid.  The button is not centered.
How can I position the DIV with the controls to be positioned beside the grid and the button to display in the center but at the bottom of the main PANEL?

This is my makeup:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnShowMappingPanel" runat="server" Text="Update Value(s) in Multiple Mappings" Width="325px" />
             <asp:Panel ID="pnlMultipleMappingControls" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="1000px" style="display:none;" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
                <div id="divMultiMapGrid" style="margin: 25px; width:45%">
                 <asp:GridView ID="msmgvMultiMappingSelection" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Caption="Select Multiple Mappings to Update" 
                        CaptionAlign="Top" CssClass="grid" Visible="true">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="msmgvCkBoxEditSelect" runat="server" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="msmgvCkBoxSelect" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mapping ID">                  
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="msmgvLblMappingID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EnrollmentMappingID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Schoology Course ID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="msmgvLblSchoologyCourseID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SchoologyCourseID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CE City Activity ID">            
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="msmgvLblCECityActivityID" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("CECityActivityID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                 </div>
                 <div id="divMultiMapControls" style="float:right; width:45%; padding:5px">
                    <div id="divMultiMapActiveCtrl" style="padding:10px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblActive"  runat="server" Text="Is Active: " CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActiveOptions" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem> </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                     <div id="divMultiMapMaxEnrollCtrl"  style="padding:10px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMaxEnrollment" runat="server" Text="Maximum Enrollment: " CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxMapEnroll" runat="server" Width="25%"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtBoxMapEnroll" runat="server" 
                                             ErrorMessage="Enter only integers." ValidationGroup="multiMapEditMappingValidation" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" 
                                             Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divMultiMapUpdateBtn">
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateSelectedMappings" runat="server" Text="Update Selected Mappings" Width="200px" CausesValidation="true" 
                    ValidationGroup="multiMapEditMappingValidation" OnClick="btnUpdateSelectedMappings_Click" /> 
                </div>
             </asp:Panel>
```

**AS REQUESTED this is the jsfiddle**

```
<panel>
<div id="divMultiMapGrid" style="margin: 25px; width:45%">Grid is here</div>
<div id="divMultiMapControls" style="float:right; width:45%; padding:5px">Controls are here
<div id="divMultiMapActiveCtrl" style="padding:10px">Dropdown control</div>
<div id="divMultiMapMaxEnrollCtrl"  style="padding:10px">text box control</div>
    </div>
<div id="divMultiMapUpdateBtn">Button</div>
```

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle out of this, using generated HTML and not the asp.net code that not everybody here understands. We also coudln't tell if you're not setting additional attributes from codebehind, so definitely seeing HTML code would be helping more.

Comment: I think you just need to add CSS float property to the Panel(I mean <asp:Panel>). Sorry, if I am wrong, I dont know about ASP.

But as per the basic understanding you need to Put float:left for the Panel.

Panel will work just like a div, so div will automatically keep the contents vertically one by one. To get your expected result, you need to work with CSS styles for your components

Comment: When I do that all of the controls move to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Don't use inline CSS. It will be very tough to manage later.

Now for your question:

```
#divMultiMapGrid {
margin: 25px;
width: 45%;
float: left;
}

#divMultiMapControls {
float: right;
width: 45%;
padding: 5px;
}

#divMultiMapActiveCtrl {
  padding: 10px;
}

#divMultiMapMaxEnrollCtrl {
  padding: 10px;
}
#divMultiMapUpdateBtn {
  clear: both;
  margin: auto;
  width: 104px; // adjust width based on button
}
```

If you are still interested only in inline style, then

```
<panel>
<div id="divMultiMapGrid" style="margin: 25px; width:45%;float: left;">Grid is here</div>
<div id="divMultiMapControls" style="float:right; width:45%; padding:5px">Controls are here
<div id="divMultiMapActiveCtrl" style="padding:10px">Dropdown control</div>
<div id="divMultiMapMaxEnrollCtrl" style="padding:10px">text box control</div>
    </div>
<div id="divMultiMapUpdateBtn" style=" clear: both; margin: auto; width: 104px;">Button</div>

</panel>
```

Comment: Your the best!  Works like a charm! Thanks!  I used the first option.

Comment: Great, very glad to hear that you have used the first option :)